# express-handlebars wont render data but renders template for the data

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I have issue with express handlebars, i try render data out of DB but i cant see text, only templates being created.
template code:

```
{{#each unapproved }}
<div class="card text-center border border-dark w-50 mx-auto bg-darkmaterial text-light">
    <div class="card-header"> {{ perustiedot }}
    </div>
</div>
<br>
{{/each}}
```

I have inserted 3 times to database so it renders 3 templates without the text. If i insert more and more it will render another empty template, also console log prints the data to console. 
i am using

```
"express": "^4.17.1",
"express-handlebars": "^3.0.2",
"express-session": "^1.17.1",
"handlebars": "^4.5.0",
```

that might help with problem.
[problem image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvtSp.png)

Comment: How are you rendering the template? And what are the values you are passing to it?

Answer (score 0):

use .lean() method on your data before printing it on UI

in your files after assigning data to these two variables do something like this
`perustiedot = perustiedot.lean() and
unapproved  =  unapproved.lean()` .